# Ghost: Display Posts From Multiple Tags On One Page

Tags: content-management-system, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I'm developing a website for a magazine using Ghost (http://ghost.org/) and would like to have pages that display posts from two related tags. Eg. "Science and Environment". I understand that when using a static page you do not have access to *posts* so I cannot for example do this. This would however be the ideal solution.

```
{{#foreach posts}}
    {{#has tag="science, environment"}}
        do thing
    {{\has}}
{{/foreach}}
```

I have had a look on the Trello roadmap (https://trello.com/b/EceUgtCL/ghost-roadmap) but couldn't spot anything there. I would appreciate any help on a workaround.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but a bit tricky

- You should install **self-hosted Ghost** . There is a lot of step-by-step manuals how to do this on Amazon, DigitalOcean, Heroku, etc.
- You should create your own custom Handlebars helper for your purposes.

  1. Create `myhelpers.js` in the Ghost project root and put your own helper code here. For example: [{{bytag}} helper](https://gist.github.com/ofstudio/d6da472641ee4d1057ec) which selects posts by *one* tag. You can extend this to query posts by more than one tag.
  2. At the beginning of `config.js` place `require('./myhelpers')();` 
     to activate your custom helper.
  3. Restart Ghost